# All urls behind firewall in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, firewall

I am creating an application which is users only. So you HAVE to log in to access any url.

At the moment I have this:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    default:
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But when I log in I get stuck on the security check. What is the best way to put all my urls behind a firewall?

Comment: what did you set in your firewall for `login_path` and `check_path`?

Comment: Entry for `/admin/` should be placed before entry for `/`, as access control rules list is evaluated untill a first match is found.

Comment: Added my firewall routes

Answer (score 2):

The acl system in symfony work as upper overriding lower ACLs.

"The order in which ACEs are checked is significant. As a general rule, you should place more specific entries at the beginning." [Symfony 2 acl Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)

So:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }                       # 4 You override #1 for all urls beginning by admin/ by allowing it to ROLE_ADMIN
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }     # 2 Same as 2
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }   # 2 Same as 2
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }  # 2 You have blocked all except this pas for IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED }                       # 1 You start by blocking all
```

Or a complete fos user files with your parameters:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                remember_me: true
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control: #Top override bottom, change order with CAUTION

        ## Admin Rule
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

        ## Anonymous FOS User Rules
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        ## Block All Website to anonymous user
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```